# How to call a function from a javascript file in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

Here is the javascript code, file saved in a different folder:

```
function PageRedirectError(location, error_code) {
    window.location.replace(location + "?error=" + error_code);
}
```

And this is the php code, file saved in a different folder:

```
<?php

echo 
'<script src="../scripts/signup_script(new).js" type="text/javascript>',
    'PageRedirectError("../location", "error_code");'
'</script>';
```

I want to do something like this, but this is probably not the correct way, so please post the correct way to do this.

Comment: you can not run php code from js

Comment: " *I want to do something like this, but this is probably not the correct way* " did you try or you are simply assuming that is not the correct way? And, if you tried, what was the result?

Comment: P.S. I recommend changing the file name from "signup_script(new).js" to something else that does not contain parenthesis.

Comment: that parentheses describes that the file is a prototype and not is used in the project

Answer (score 0):

When you want to redicrect the user to a specific page of error,
you can use the php header() function,

So in PHP code, while you are catching an error the redicrection of user can be done with: 

Php Page

```
<?php
header('Location: ?error=$error');
?>
```

then in your Js:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const error_message = urlParams.get('error')
alert(error_message);
```

Comment: I don't only want to redirect the user but also want to perform some actions with javascript after redirecting, that's the reason why i used javascript to redirect the page as after using "header" function i can't call anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using JS inside PHP files but if you really want to...

Remember that your JavaScript code is client side and PHP is server side but it is actually possible to use JS inside PHP files. You can echo or better is to use herdoc or nowdoc and I suggest reading this article [JavaScript inside PHP](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-write-JavaScript-code-inside-PHP)